# How do I uniquely tag file and it's various versions?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I am working on a small application to allow me modify files and version each file before each change. What I would like the app to do is uniquely mark each file so that whenever the same file is opened up, the history for that particular file can be pulled back up. I am not using any of the big version control tools for this. How do I do this pro grammatically please?

Comment: I'm confused, is your question how to write your own version control system so you don't have to use an existing one?

Comment: Well you say you're *not* using an existing version control solution - the obvious question is "why not?" - I suggest you try using Git, Mercurial or something similar. You don't necessarily need *centralized* version control with a server or anything like that. Something local may well be fine.

Comment: I would rather have my own code that does this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution. Use a verison control which already exists (eg. Git) but if your really want to do this then try this.

Each time you create a new version copy the previous version of the file into a separate hidden directory and have a config file in that directory which holds the checksum of that file. Checksum will "more than likely" be unique since its a hashed value of the file (each time file changes, checksum will be different - you need to calculate the checksum yourself.)

When you open a file just check if there is that config file in the directory and compare the checksum with the checksum of what's already open. If they are the same then you are on the same file. That's how it works.

You could use checksums to optimise it. So if a user goes in to a file changes things, changes back to the way they were and saves. Checksum should return the same thing (unless you include modified date and time etc.)

Each folder should have a name which follows a pattern (filenameVn.n eg. someTextFile.txt.v1.0) then you will be able to figure out what the directory you are navigating to in the history should say.

Another approach would be to simply copy the file and append some tag onto the end of it (checksum maybe? version number?) so then you wouldn't need extra folders.

Yet another approach would be to call the files whatever the checksum recorded and store the history of versions (along with corresponding checksums) in a separate config file and then refer to it when you want to figure out what the file that you want to access is called. So each version will be refered to based on its own checksum (like in Git.)

So to sum up each file version would be stored somewhere, you will be able to validate if they are the same (so you can optimise by avoiding storing multiple files with no changes in them and wasting space) and you will be able to dynamically determine where each version is and get access to it.

Hope it gives you a bit more understanding of how to get started.